# Integrating external plugin with rsyslog

Tags: perl, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to write an `external plugin` for `rsyslog in perl` for my use. I am able to get basic skeleton from github but i am not able to get any info on how to integrate it with rsyslog setup. I read `interface.md` on github and it ask to read documentation for `mmexternal` native plugin which i am unable to find anywhere.

Apart from what above i also updated my `/etc/rsyslog` file with

```
module(load="omprog")
*.* action(type="omprog" action="path to my plugin")
```

What i updated above is based on given slide http://www.slideshare.net/rainergerhards1/writing-rsyslog-p

Still i am not able to get desired result.

Can anyone tell me how to integrate external plugin with rsyslog setup and then sending logs to external machine after modification?

NOTE:- rsyslog is running on a debian machine and external machine on which logs will be send is also debian. I am writing external plugin on first machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i found is that rsyslog is case sensitive and i only need to change `module` to `Module` and it start working perfectly.